# Sum by month in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to sum my daily data (trunc(DM_OWNER.LD_LEG_DW.CPLD_DTT) by month. This is created in a Web Intelligence BI report.

```
SELECT
  DM_OWNER.LD_LEG_DW.LGST_GRP_CD,
  DM_OWNER.LGST_GRP_T.LGSTGRP_DESC,
  DM_OWNER.LD_LEG_DW.CARR_CD,
  DM_OWNER.LD_LEG_DW.LD_LEG_ID,
  DM_OWNER.LD_LEG_DW.BILL_TO_CUST_CD,
  trunc(DM_OWNER.LD_LEG_DW.CPLD_DTT),
  trunc(DM_OWNER.VCHR_AP_T.CRTD_DTT),
  AP_Detail.PYMNT_AMT_DLR
FROM
  DM_OWNER.LD_LEG_DW,
  DM_OWNER.LGST_GRP_T,
  DM_OWNER.VCHR_AP_T,
  DM_OWNER.CHRG_DETL_T_NOTOTAL_V  AP_Detail
WHERE
  ( DM_OWNER.LD_LEG_DW.LD_LEG_ID=DM_OWNER.VCHR_AP_T.LD_LEG_ID(+)  )
  AND  ( DM_OWNER.VCHR_AP_T.VCHR_NUM=AP_Detail.VCHR_NUM_AP  )
  AND  ( DM_OWNER.LD_LEG_DW.LGST_GRP_CD=DM_OWNER.LGST_GRP_T.LGST_GRP_CD  )
  AND  
  (
   DM_OWNER.LD_LEG_DW.LGST_GRP_CD  In  ( 'PBRK'  )
   AND
   trunc(DM_OWNER.VCHR_AP_T.CRTD_DTT)  >=  '01-10-2012 00:00:00'
  )
```

Comment: Which field(s) contain the date you are trying to GROUP BY?  What data type is it?  What fields are you trying to aggregate?  What data types are they?  Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Dems: Probably Oracle, judging by the `(+)` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @AndriyM - Afaik that's standard to several RDBMS when not using ANSI-92 syntax.

Comment: @Dems: Ah, I see, thanks, didn't know that, thought it was Oracle's proprietary syntax extension.

Answer (score 2):

Without clear field names, or an explanation of the data structure, this is too vague. But the principle is

```
select 
     displayfields,
     year(datefield), month(datefield), 
     sum(valuefield)
from yourtable
group by 
     displayfields,
     year(datefield), month(datefield),
```

Comment: And if the data spans more than one year?

Comment: @dems then I add the year function.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the specifics of your query, here's a general approach.

The CAST is nasty, but this has the benefit of giving you an actual DATETIME as a grouper.

```
SELECT
   SUM(Amount) AS MonthTotal,
   CAST(CAST(YEAR(DateCollected) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
     + '/' + CAST(MONTH(DateCollected) AS VARCHAR(2)) 
     + '/01' AS DATETIME) AS PaymentMonth
FROM
   PaymentsReceived
GROUP BY
   CAST(CAST(YEAR(DateCollected) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
     + '/' + CAST(MONTH(DateCollected) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01' AS DATETIME)
```